# stretch across the width of page for radio button in jqm 1.2.0 iOS device

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to make the horizontal radio button to full width of the screen and I am referring http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/ and my code is below:

```
     <div> 
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
 <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="spent_money_1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" /> <label for="spent_money_1">Spent Some $</label>
 <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="made_money_1" value="choice-2"/>
 <label for="made_money_1">Made Some $</label> 
 </fieldset>
 </div>
```

and i tried to put style="width:100%" in both div, fieldset and input but doesn't help either. Appreciate any advice please. thanks !

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

I have been having the same problem. Adding the following CSS works for me.

This case is for 4 radio buttons, so I use 25% width for ui-radio.

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls
{
    width:100%;
}
.ui-radio {
    width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the general case where you don't want to specify the widths (works in 1.3.0)

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-radio
{
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```